# bitbake: how to add package depending on MACHINE?

Tags: cross-platform, yocto, bitbake

My images, built with `bitbake`, must contain different packages for different machines (say, I need to add package `package1` to image for `machine1`, but not for `machine2`).

It is possible to add line

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1 = " package1"
```

to the image recipe. But I do not think this is sustainable, as `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1` may be defined in some other recipe (which is not under my control) and the earlier definition gets overwritten with the later one. This is what I think Yocto Project Development manual [warns about using IMAGE_INSTALL](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL).

Is my concern valid? What is the proper way to write the recipe(s) in this case?

Comment: As far as I know and understand the documentation `IMAGE_INSTALL*` should only be used in "image recipes", but there its usage is perfectly fine.
Where (package recipe, image recipe, config, ...) did you added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1`?

Comment: @g0hl1n: I have added it to the image recipe.

Comment: Then it should be fine as far as I know. The only improvement i can imagine is to "append to the append": `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1 += " package1"`. 
That's the way I'm using it for years without problems.

Comment: @g0hl1n Could you explain how `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1 += " package1"` work?  If IMAGE_INSTALL is an array, what would IMAGE_INSTALL be like with IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1 + = " "? 2D array? Sorry, I have never seen this way of using IMAGE_INSTALL_append.

Comment: @LightenS to be honest, I don't know for sure how it really works. I am only guessing: `IMAGE_INSTALL` is basically a string containing package names, separated by spaces. The same goes for `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` and `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine`. So it should be possible to just attach another "space separated" String to those variables. Finally somewhere in the core all `IMAGE_INSTALL` variables get merged and are then intepreted...    _As I already wrote, this is only my understanding of the process, don't take it as a fact!_ P.S.: If somebody has a link to the "real facts", please share!

Comment: @g0hl1n I did some experiment regarding IMAGE_INSTALL the way you did and use `bitbake -e | grep IMAGE_INSTALL`.  You would only need to use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append_machine1 = " "`.  When the machine variable is equal to `machine`, the item will be added to `IMAGE_INSTALL`, interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is `base_contains`

> This functions is used to set a variable to one of two values based on
>   the definition of a third variable.
>
> `${@base_contains('variable-name', 'value', 'true-result', 'false-result',d)}"` where:
>
> variable-name This is the name of a variable to check.
>
> value This is the value to compare the variable against.
>
> true-result If the variable equals the value then this is what is
>   returned by the function.
>
> false-result If the variable does not equal the value then this is
>   what is returned by the function.

One more thing, you could use `??=` to provide a default value.  The differences between `?=` and `??=` is that with `??=` the assignment does not occur until the end of the parsing process.

You could take a look at one of the example [here](http://elinux.org/ECE597_OpenEmbedded_Issues_and_Problem_Solving) for image recipe

http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_advanced_python.html

Comment: Thank you. For my case, `@base_conditional()` is what I need.

Comment: Bitbake has been updated since. For those who are looking, replace `base_contains` by `bb.utils.contains`. Thanks for the doc link!